# merging files based on common column in bash shell

Tags: linux

I have two files like this:

file1.txt

```
USA
Italy
Canada
France
```

file2.txt

```
Australia TRUE
Belize    TRUE
Canada    FALSE
CostaRica TRUE
France    FALSE
Holland   TRUE
Italy     TRUE
Mongolia  FALSE
USA       FALSE
```

I would like to merge the files based on common rows and have this output first:

```
USA    FALSE
Italy  TRUE
Canada FALSE
France FALSE
```

Then I would like to convert the FALSE to 0 and TRUE to 1

```
USA    0
Italy  1
Canada 0
France 0
```

The order of the countries in the output file has to be strictly the same as input, no sorting, so I cannot use the join command

Any suggestion on the linux commands which I could use?

Comment: You want to [`join`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) the files.

Comment: I cant do that because I need to sort alphabetically the lines and as I said I need to maintain the order of the input

Comment: You can. Number the lines in the first file with `nl`. Join them on fields. Re-sort using the numbers you inserted into the file. Remove the numbers. Something like `nl -w1 file1.txt | sort -k2 | join -12 -21 - <(sort -k1 file2.txt) | sort -n -k1 | cut -f2-`.

Comment: oh yeah I could try that...thanks

Comment: thank you very much, everything is working, very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [sort](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) the files
2. [join](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) them
3. [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) the output
4. ([column](https://linux.die.net/man/1/column)ate them if you want)

example:

```
$ join -j1 <(sort -k1 file1.txt) <(sort -k1 file2.txt) | sed 's/TRUE/1/g; s/FALSE/0/g' # | column -t -s' '
```

Note: this will however reorder your result to:

```
Canada 0
France 0
Italy  1
USA    0
```

Comment: what happens if you try to sort the files only? `sort -k1 file1.txt` and `sort -k1 file2.txt`. Do the files have an empty line at the end, or somewhere else?

Comment: it gives me an empty file

Comment: but when I join I get an empty file

Comment: does the rows need to be spaced?